# DOORS / DXL object attribute "Last Modified On" including time?

Tags: ibm-doors

I understand how to access an object's modification date using the `Last Modified On` attribute. Is there any hidden / undocumented way to access the **modification time** with DOORS 9.5? In my case, I want to identify changes since a certain daytime, thus the date is not precise enough.

According to [this post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014537532) at the IBM forum, the attribute was supposed to return date and time. However, the output of this statement:

```
Date lastModified = obj."Last Modified On"
print "dateAndTime = " (dateAndTime(lastModified)) "\tlastModified = " lastModified "\tdateOnly = " dateOnly(lastModified) "\n"
```

is in my case

```
dateAndTime = 08/04/14 00:00:00     lastModified = 04 August 2014   dateOnly = 04 August 2014
```

and I guess that this means that the change time was not provided (correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section "History" of the DXL manual describes the function `Date lastModifiedTime({Module|Object|Link})` which provides the desired time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `Last Modified On` attribute is only storing the date without a time. In order to get the time of the last modification, you would need to step through the history records on the object and get the time from the last record. This will also be an issue because any object that hasn't changed since the baseline will have no history records against it.

Comment: Thanks to the alternative approach you suggested (which could probably be used to tinker something for my use case), I read the manual's "History" section and came across the function `lastModifiedTime()` which returns date and time!
It's a bit odd to find such a function in there, but well! Thanks for pointing into that direction!

Comment: Good to know, you should post that as the answer to your question so others can use in the future.